# How to Copy and Paste Rows starting from a specific cell in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy all the rows from the `Pipeline Report` sheet that contain the text *"AllScripts"* in column *T*.

Then, I want to paste them onto another sheet starting from *"A14"* and go down.

Right now this code pastes them from "A2" but I need it to start from A14 and go down from there.

```
Sub extractAllscripts() 

Dim myrange As Range 
Dim lr as Long

Sheets("Pipeline Report").Select 
Set myrange = Sheets("Pipeline Report").Range("T1", Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 

For Each cell In myrange 
    If cell.Value = "Allscripts" Then 
        lr = Sheets("Macro Test Page").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Macro Test Page").Range("A" & lr + 1) 
    End If 
Next cell 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad practice but as we don't know how your sheet is set up, then I would suggest this:

```
Sub extractAllscripts() 

Dim myrange As Range 
Dim lr as Long
Dim myoffset As Integer

Sheets("Pipeline Report").Select 
Set myrange = Sheets("Pipeline Report").Range("T1", Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 

myoffset = 13

For Each cell In myrange 
 If cell.Value = "Allscripts" Then 
     lr = Sheets("Macro Test Page").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Macro Test Page").Range("A" & lr + myoffset) 
    End If
    myoffset = 1 
Next cell 

End Sub
```

Or another bad solution:

In your code substitute `lr = Sheets("Macro Test Page").Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` with `lr = lr + 1` and define `lr` to be 13 outside of the loop and in the `Range("A" & lr + 1)` use `lr` instead of `lr + 1`.